# Filtering out certain columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to filter out certain columns in my pandas dataframe based on the column name.

So the frame is roughly:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_build = {'Var_1_Reading': [1,2,3,10,0.1], 'Var_1_Confidence':[1,1,1,1,1], 'Var_2_Reading': [1,2,3,10,0.1], 'Var_2_Confidence':[1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_build)
```

I want to drop the columns with `Confidence` at the end. I tried with `filter` but couldn't work it out. At the moment I am doing:

```
ColList_to_drop = df.filter(regex='Confidence', axis=1).columns.values
filtered_df = df.drop(ColList_to_drop, axis = 1)
```

Can I just do these two steps all in the regex?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
>>> cols = [col for col in df.columns if not col.endswith('Confidence')]    
>>> df = df[cols]

>>> df
   Var_1_Reading  Var_2_Reading
0            1.0            1.0
1            2.0            2.0
2            3.0            3.0
3           10.0           10.0
4            0.1            0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [negative lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions) `(?!...)`:

```
print df.filter(regex='^(?!.*Confidence).*$')
   Var_1_Reading  Var_2_Reading
0            1.0            1.0
1            2.0            2.0
2            3.0            3.0
3           10.0           10.0
4            0.1            0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the str methods on the column index directly, as:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('Confidence')]
```

Comment: I just realized that you wanted to drop the columns instead of select them. So I added a negation on the column filter.